# Comments system by id

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am a programmer at asp.net core mvc,
Image:

[image]

I want to do such a thing but belong by id

I was able to do the first part I add data to database and associate it with id,
but can not display the messages.
I will show the code I tried to do but when I try to do foreach I get NullReferenceException

My Controller:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index1()
    {

        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index1(Comment comment, int id)
    {
        ModelState.Clear();
        TryValidateModel(comment);
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var animal = await _context.Animals.FindAsync(id);
            comment.Animal = animal!;
            _context.Add(comment);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index1));
        }

        return View(_context.Comments.ToList());
    }
```

My Partial View:

```
@model PetShop.Data.Models.Comment

<form method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Content" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Content" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Content" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="click me"/>
```

My View:

```
@model IEnumerable<PetShop.Data.Models.Comment>
@await Html.PartialAsync("_MyPatial")

@if(Model != null)

{
  foreach(var item in Model)
{
    @item.Content
}
```

}

Note: here I do not get null because I made a condition but I want it to do and display, my problem is to only display the messages that are registered or exist in the database

image: [image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add the screenshots of your List of `Animal` page where you would click on each details and then can be seen this comment list under  an amimal.

Comment: You missed another page, This is when you would click on the details `Button`, where is the details page. I mean `Category page` there is a button I can see `back to catetory page` that page I need

Comment: Okay, checking that, meanwhile delete few of your comment here, and [`read this article`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71862936/naming-convention-for-webapi-that-return-boolean-value/71866375#71866375)would help you.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Sorry but I did not understand how this relates to my problem?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I just need to do a foreach on the content and display them

Comment: If you you now add new comment it can save to database right? Now you want to disply them below once you add new comment right?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Load Animal List:`**

> **`Controller:`**
>
> ```cs
> public IActionResult Index()
> {
>     var animal = _context.Animals.ToList();
>     return View(animal);
> }
> ```
>
> **`View:`**
>
> ```cs
> @model IEnumerable<MVCApps.Models.Animal>
>
> @{
>     ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
> }
>
> <h2>Animal List</h2>
>
> <p>
>     <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
> </p>
> <table class="table">
>     <thead>
>         <tr>
>             <th>
>                 @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
>             </th>
>             <th>
>                 @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category)
>             </th>
>             <th>
>                 @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
>             </th>
>             <th>
>                 Animal Details
>             </th>
>         </tr>
>     </thead>
>     <tbody>
> @foreach (var item in Model) {
>         <tr>
>             <td>
>                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
>             </td>
>             <td>
>                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)
>             </td>
>             <td>
>                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
>             </td>
>             <td>
>                 <a asp-action="Details" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-id="@item.AnimalId">Details</a> 
>             </td>
>         </tr>
> }
>     </tbody>
> ```
>
> **`Output:`**
>
> [image]

**`Load Animal Details:`**

**`Controller:`**

```cs
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            var objAnimal = _context.Animals.Where(aId => aId.AnimalId == id).FirstOrDefault();


            AnimalViewModel _animal = new AnimalViewModel();
            _animal.AnimalId = objAnimal.AnimalId;
            _animal.Name = objAnimal.Name;
            _animal.Category = objAnimal.Category;
            _animal.Description = objAnimal.Description;

            return View(_animal);
        }
```

**`View Model:`**

```cs
public class AnimalViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int AnimalId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

**`View For Animal Details:`**

```cs
@model MVCApps.Models.AnimalViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}



<div>
    <h4><strong>Animal Details</strong> </h4>
  
    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped">

        <tr>
            <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</th>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category)</th>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Category)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)</th>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <!-- TextBox Post Comment -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form id="postCommentByAnimalId">
                    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post Comment</button>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="Content" name="Content" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your comment" />
                                <input type="text" id="AnimalId" hidden name="AnimalId" value="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AnimalId)" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Back To List", "Index", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
                            </th>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>



                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        @*This is where your comment partial view will appear appear when user hits submit on our form*@
        <div id="commentDisplay"></div>
    </div>


</div>
@section scripts {
    <script>
       //This Fucntion Load All the Comment based on Amimal Id 
        function LoadAllComment(animalId) {

            var Comment = {
                AnimalId: $("#AnimalId").val()

            };
            console.log(Comment);
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "https://localhost:44361/Amimal/PostComment",
                data: Comment,
                success: function (result) {
                    //When then load our partial view into our containing div on the main page
                    $('#commentDisplay').html(result);

                }
            });
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Get animal Id which List of comment need to load
            var animalId = '@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AnimalId)'

            //Displaying comment for specific Animal when details button clicked
            LoadAllComment(animalId);
            //When the user hit the submit button we will post the form results to our partial view controller

            $('#postCommentByAnimalId').submit(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "https://localhost:44361/Amimal/PostComment",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        //When then load our partial view into our containing div on the main page
                        $('#commentDisplay').html(result);
                          //Clear Comment Text Box after posting comment
                        $("#Content").val("");
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`Post Comment and Display Controller & Partial View:`**

**`Controller:`**

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostComment([Bind("Content,AnimalId")] Comment comment, int id)
        {
            if (comment.Content != null)
            {
                _context.Comments.Add(comment);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                ModelState.Clear();
            }

            List<Comment> commentList = _context.Comments.Where(cmId => cmId.AnimalId == comment.AnimalId).ToList();


            return PartialView(commentList);
        }
```

**`Partial View:`**

```cs
@model IEnumerable<MVCApps.Models.Comment>
<div class="panel-body">
    @if (Model != null || Model.Count() < 1)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("PostComment", "Amimal", FormMethod.Post))
        {

            <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td> @item.Content <br /><input hidden name="id" value="@item.CommentId" /> </td>
                    </tr>

                }

            </table>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <p>No results found</p>
    }
</div>
```

**`Final Output:`**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help,
I successfully do it in a different way

Comment: That's great, I was little worried about if it's seems bit complicated for you. There are even better way to handle this features using `ViewComponent` but at this moment It might seen complicated for you however [`ViewComponent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0#view-components) itself a very powerful funtionality. Anyway,  Glad to see that you have done it.

Comment: The way you did looks good but I have not yet learned ajax and jquery I used viewmodel with Comment table and list <Comment> and worked on it

Comment: I have also used `viewModel` as well. No worries

Comment: I uploaded you can look :)

Comment: No problem I will thanks that out. thanks