# How to pass data from one controller to another using .Net Core web api

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have created two different table tbl1 and tbl2.
I am trying to POST data in tbl2 using web api, having tbl1 Id. unable to do POST webapi.
PLEASE HELP.

```
**Tbl1**
Tbl1Id   Name       
11       Rajesh

**Tbl2**
Tbl2Id  City        Tbl1Id  
123     Pune        11
```

Comment: This does not sound like it has anything to do with Web API. It seems like you are not handling your database logic correctly. Again, your question and information is extremely vague so it's hard to tell.

Comment: If you want to do - it means that you are doing something wrong. But yes, it is possible to call from your controller's method using httpclient/webrequest etc. and hardcode the url you are going to call into httpclient/webrequest call. But it is ugly way to do it. It is just fyi.

Comment: How your controller looks like could you share with us? So that it can be resolved easily. You can get the [`example here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71853701/comments-system-by-id)